# will base_subtotal_incl_tax field in sales_flat_order contain price including reward points currency in magento

Tags: magento

```
 When i looked at an order in sales_flat_order table in Magento , i see fields total_paid and total_invoiced have correct prices with deducted rewards currency , but on the base_subtotal_incl_tax it only shows the total amount with tax without deducting the rewards currency. Is that how its supposed to be? . ex:

base_subtotal_incl_tax => 144.17
total_paid =>143.17
total_invoiced =>143.17
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Thank you,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is correct. If you look into *app/code/core/Enterprise/Reward/Model/Total/Quote/Reward.php*, you can find:

```
            $address->setGrandTotal($address->getGrandTotal() - $pointsCurrencyAmountUsed);
            $address->setBaseGrandTotal($address->getBaseGrandTotal() - $basePointsCurrencyAmountUsed);
```

So the Reward will discount only the GrandTotal and BaseGrandTotal by default.